# Android BLE smartband

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can anyone tell me how to get data from smartband in my android app?
From onServicesDiscovered I don't know what to do...

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
            Log.w("Service", service.getUuid().toString());
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : gatt.getService(service.getUuid()).getCharacteristics()) {
                    Log.e("Characteristic", characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your smart band brand and model. The most convenient way is to use API provided by smart band manufacturer.

Comment: My smart band is Mio MiVia™ Essential 350

Comment: I don't see any API or library for this band. Try to ask here http://www.mivia.com